# AlertDialog.Builder.setView() will load wrong resource on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog, android-support-library, android-resources

I am creating different dialog layout for different API platforms, by specifying res/layout-v11 for platforms later than Android HoneyComb and earlier devices should load from the default res/layout directory. However, this mechanism seems to be broken after I update my target-api and support library. The final APK works fine on my NexusS with Android 4.1, but will load default layout on my Nexsu5 and Nexus7, both with Android 5.1.1.

It is a strange problem since the activity layout differentiated with layout-vX is still working, only the dialog layout is wrong.

Sample code:

MainActivity.java: (I tried both android.app.AlertDialog and android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog, the behavior is the same)

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View dialogView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.alert, null);
        builder.setView(dialogView);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

res/layout/alert.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2.0dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/web_site_add_terms_contents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="alert box from res/layout"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/web_site_add_terms_agree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/web_site_add_terms_contents"
        android:text="check box"
        android:color="@android:color/black" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

res/layout-v11/alert.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2.0dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/web_site_add_terms_contents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="alert box from res/layout-v11" />
    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/web_site_add_terms_agree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/web_site_add_terms_contents"
        android:text="check box v11" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Simple build and launch the application on NexusS(4.1.2), Nexus5(5.1.1) and Nexus7(5.1.1), the results are:

1. NexusS: dialog displaying 'v11' text
2. Nexus5: dialog displaying default text
3. Nexus7: dialog displaying default text

Any help or hint will be appreciated.

---

***update***

I add another resource folder in res/layout-v21/alert.xml and it works for my Lollipop devices! Anyone can explain the trick?

res/layout-v21/alert.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="2.0dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/web_site_add_terms_contents"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="alert box from res/layout-v21" />
    <CheckBox 
        android:id="@+id/web_site_add_terms_agree"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/web_site_add_terms_contents"
        android:text="check box v21" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I build this application, and it displays 'v11' on my  NexusS and 'v21' on my Nexus5 and Nexus7. I was so confused now.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify which version your layout will apply, by placing them in layout-vxx, with xx is Platform Version. For example, layout-v21 will apply to Android 5.0 and newer, so your Nexus 5 (5.1.1, API version 22) will use layout from this folder. Your Nexus S is in Android version 4.1.2 (API level 16) so it will use layout from layout-v11.
More detail in Google document:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html